# How can I enable Huawei Push Kit? Authentication parameters needed

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-push-notification, appgallery-connect

I do all the steps according to the Huawei documentation
First, I enabled the Push Kit api through the **Project Settings -> Manage Apis**

Then I go to the **Grow -> Push Kit** and turn on Push Kit there, after which I turn on precise messaging:
[image]

After that, I try to enable precise messaging for my app, but instead I see this window
[image]

I did not find any information about what to write in the Authentication parameters window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing this problem, then most likely you do not have enough rights for these actions.

You need to contact the account owner and ask to expand your rights and permissions

Comment: Despite these parameters aren't documented - they're not required either.

Comment: @MartinZeitler if you do not fill in this input field and click "accept" you will get an error
In addition, after enabling the Push Kit, push notifications should be enabled automatically and the user should see not only the "settings" tab, but also other tabs, such as "notifications" and "complaints". What's not available without developer rights extension

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, precision marketing has been enabled. For authentication parameters of Configure other android-based push , pls kindly check the [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/3rd-party-push-integration-0000001050992231?ha_source=hms1).

The settings do not affect the normal sending and receiving of Huawei push messages. If you are not sure whether to enable or disable the settings, you do not need to enable or configure the settings.

In addition, according to the screenshot you provided, only **Setting** options are available for the Push Kit service, and other notifications are unavailable. In this case, your team administrator needs to configure operation permissions for your account.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the document, screenshot and answer to your question below. You need to copy-and-paste the JSON key file of the target platform into Authentication parameters.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/3rd-party-push-integration-0000001050992231

[image]

[image]